# create function to test whether MORE THAN 2 dataframes are different

Tags: python, function, unit-testing, assert

I have a list of dataframes like this (in df_lst) and i need to check which are different.

**here are some data frames**

```
from pandas._testing import assert_frame_equal
d1 = pd.DataFrame({1: [10], 2: [20]})
d2 = pd.DataFrame({1: [10], 2: [20]})
d3 = pd.DataFrame({1: [11], 2: [20]})
d4 = pd.DataFrame({1: [11], 2: [20]})
d5 = pd.DataFrame({1: [9], 2: [20]})

df_lst=[d1,d2,d3,d4,d5]
```

I know you can check with e.g. this command

```
assert_frame_equal(d1,d3)
```

But ideally, it has to be as a function or something that lets you input the list of dataframes - the below code does not work as its missing an argument. it should terminate at this point if it fails to be equal

```
def check_equality (df_lst):
    for i in df_lst:
        assert_frame_equal(i)
```

any comments welcome. thanks so much!

Comment: Are you really writing a unit test here? Or are you performing some logic with your data frame to check equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comparing a list against a single known correct dataframe, you can do this:

```
def check_equality(df_lst, correct_df):
    for i in df_lst:
        assert_frame_equal(correct_df, i)
```

If you want to do pairwise comparisons of all dataframes in the list, `(a, b), (a, c), (a, d), (b, c), etc...` you can try this:

```
from itertools import product

def check_equality(df_lst):
    for pair in product(df_lst, repeat=2):
        assert_frame_equal(pair[0], pair[1])
```

Comment: thanks so much the pairwise comparisons is exactly what i wanted. however it doesn't tell me which of the dataframes actually differ, just where the difference is. do you know if that can be incorporated in to this function? else i have to do 'manual' comparisons anyway (e.g., df1 = a.compare(b), df2 = a.compare(c), df3 - b.compare(c), lst=(df1 ,df2, df3), pd.concat(lst)) to see the differences

Comment: In the for() loop, you can print the pair[0] and pair[1] in addition to the result. Otherwise, you may need to use a dictionary to associate each a name with each dataframe, the function would work pretty much the same except df_list would be df_dict